# How to get list of entities corresponding to tables in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

In EF Core's derived `DbContext`, in the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method, I can get all entity types defined in the model by calling `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()`.

My problem is that some of my entities have properties of complex types, i.e. the property type is a class rather than a string or a number. Those classes used in property definitions also become entities defined in the model and are returned by `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()`. How can I get only the entities that correspond to DB tables?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create C# console app.
2. Add EF and Npgsql nuget packages:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.3" />
```

3. Replace the content of `Program.cs` with the following:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseNpgsql().Options;
        MyDbContext myDbContext = new(options);
        myDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; private set; }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.StoreAsJson).HasColumnType("jsonb");
        var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(et => !et.IsOwned()).ToList();
    }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public StoreAsJson StoreAsJson { get; set; }
}

public class StoreAsJson
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

4. Put a breakpoint after the line `var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(et => !et.IsOwned()).ToList();`
5. Run the program and check how many entities `entityTypes` contains.

**One possible solution to the problem**

For now I solved this as follows:

```
HashSet<Type> entityClrTypes = typeof(MyDbContext).GetProperties()
    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
    .Select(pi => pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
    .ToHashSet();
List<IMutableEntityType> entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(et => EntityClrTypes.Contains(et.ClrType))
    .ToList();
```

List of `DbSets` in the `DbContext` will not necessarily correspond to the tables that will be created in the DB, but in my case it does.

Comment: What do you mean by "entities that correspond to DB tables"? Even the complex types (called owned entity types in EF Core) have associated db tables where they are stored and read. If you are trying to eliminate these, there is `IsOwned()` method which can be used as criteria, e.g. `GetEntityTypes().Where(entityType => !entityType.IsOwned())`

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. In my case the property of a complex type is mapped not to a table but rather to a column in a table. My database in Postgres, it has column type `jsonb`. If I configure the complex property as follows `builder.Property(e => e.MyComplexProperty).HasColumnType("jsonb")`, EF Core provider for Postgres automatically serialise/deserialise my complex property to/from JSON when storing/retrieving it. Also just to make sure, I tried your filter by `IsOwned()`, I still get the unwanted entity.

Comment: So you are not using "standard" EFC 7.0 [Mapping to JSON columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#mapping-to-json-columns) (which as I understand is still not supported by Npgsql provider), but Npgsql provider specific [JSON Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco). Such details should be included in the question/tags. Also I could not reproduce the problem - in my test (EFC 7.0, latest NpgSql), POCOs mapped to `jsonb` columns are not returned from `GetEntityTypes()`.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev. Yes I use Npgsql provider JSON mapping as described on the paged you linked to. I've updated the question with steps to reproduce. When I run the code I posted, `entityTypes` contains both `MyEntity` and `StoreAsJson`

Comment: Strange. I see no special metadata for these "entities", yet they are not included in the migration. There must be some trick in Npgsql provider, you'd better ask in their issue tracker, or eventually hope/wait [Shay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640325/shay-rojansky)(the owner of Npgsql) to notice this question (added `npgsql` tag if that helps) and answer here.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. I posted another update to the question, how I solved this for myself for now. I know it's not a proper solution to the problem "get all entities that correspond to tables", but in my case it works.